# Run for loop sequence and stop random not only the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

Hi i am new to jquery/javascript , i have a for loop where at, i need to run it in sequence from 1 to 4. but when the "for loop" stop, the element should stop either 1,2,3 or 4 (randomly). is it possible? cause now what i did is , it always stop in count 4. kindly help. Thank you..

You can access the code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-hodgkin-esr8f?file=/index.html:0-904

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
      type="text/javascript"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body style="background: gray;">
    <button id="k">Hello</button>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  var data = [
    {
      count: "1",
      name: "one"
    },
    {
      count: "2",
      name: "two"
    },
    {
      count: "3",
      name: "three"
    },
    {
      count: "4",
      name: "four"
    }
  ];

  $("#k").click(function () {
    let count = 0;
    const interVal = setInterval(function () {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // loop through the data array
        const _data = data[i];
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log("data", _data.count);
        }, 50 * i);
      }
      count += 1;
      if (count === 3) clearInterval(interVal);
    }, 600);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What are the `setInterval` and `setTimeout`s meant to be doing? Your question doesn't address those, just the loop.

Comment: setinterval i use because i run the for loop repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest answer would be to generate a random number between the range you are interested in, and use that number to be the end of the for loop. You can use the following function:

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
}
```

That will return a random integer with min included and max excluded. If you add that to your code, the call to your for loop can be something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= getRndInteger(1, 5); i++) {
```

Hope it helped!

Hint: You should always provide a smaller version of your code, the minimun to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to randomize the number of loopings with for. So doing following steps:

```
//Add code to generate a random number
const random = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

//Modify thel clearIntervl line:
if (count == random) clearInterval(interVal);
```